# OpenCV CMAKE libraries extension for C++ Builder 64 bit

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I am trying to build OpenCV 3.2.0 libraries for Rad Studio 10.2.3 (C++ Builder 64 bit) on Windows 10
I am using CMake 3.17.0 following the procedure below:

https://github.com/IgorYunusov/OpenCV-RS

The problem is that the libraries generated are for a 32 bit application (.lib). And I need libraries for a C++ Builder 64 bit application (.a).
So I first changed the compiler to BCC64.exe and I added the following variables in CMAKE GUI interface:

```
CMAKE_CXX_OUTPUT_EXTENSION  .o 
CMAKE_LINK_LIBRARY_SUFFIX   .a 
CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX  a 
CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX .a 
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES  a 
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES .a
```

But when I run make install on Rad Studio command line, the generated libraries are always .lib
It seems that for Windows, CMake will always generate .lib files?
So, how to configure CMake, using the GUI, so that it will generate configuration files to build 64 bit (.a) libraries files?

Comment: ***It seems that for Windows, CMake will always generate .lib files?*** No, this is incorrect. It will generate using the toolchain you told it to use. Type `cmake ---help` and look at the generators section. You don't want to use any of the Visual Studio generators or nmake ones.

Comment: Thanks. But in this case I am not using a toolchain. Instead, I am using Borland MakeFiles with Clang native compiler for 64 bit application: BCC64.exe

Comment: A toolchain means a compiler + linker.

Comment: In the GUI I am using, there is an option called "Specify a toolchain..." which is totally different from the option to select a compiler like I do. This is what I am talking about.

Comment: I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution
I added the 2 lines below in the Windows-Embarcadero.cmake file which was copied to the CMake 3.17 installation directory:

```
if(CMAKE_BASE_NAME STREQUAL "bcc64")
  set(CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX ".a")
  set(CMAKE_OUTPUT_EXTENSION ".o")
endif()
```

Now I need to test the generated .a libraries to see if they are really 64 bit libraries!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solutions that do not require compiling the source code：
generate import library from .dll for x64 platform:

```
mkexp.exe -p xxx.a xxx.dll
```

for x86 platform:

```
implib -a xxx.lib xxx.dll
```